# Flutter - type 'Booking' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter

I'm struggling with following lines of code :

```
  var arguments = Get.arguments as Map<String,dynamic>;
  user.value = arguments['user'] as User;
  heroTag = arguments['heroTag'] as String;
```

type 'Booking' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Anyone have any idea what may be a problem or how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the rest of your code. what is Get.argument, why are you casting it as `Map`?  `arguments` is an object of type `Booking`.

Comment: get.argument is   dynamic get arguments => routing.args; and casting is at Map as ive followed tutorial to start chat over firestore.

Comment: But it's not a map, it's a `Booking` object. try accessing it using `.`, i.e `user.value = arguments.user`, and post more code, it's very hard to give advice with this very minimal snippet.